Importing Proto.Actor proto file in custom protobuf
I can't find my way around importing the Protos.proto file from Proto.Actor in my own protobuf definition file.
In the examples from GitHub, the project is referencing the Proto.Actor project directly, but using the nuget package I'm not able to import it. It always says "File not found" during the ProtoGen task.
Here's an example of such include :
https://github.com/asynkron/protoactor-dotnet/blob/dev/examples/Chat/Messages/Chat.proto
I want to be able to use the type PID (or actor.PID since the proto package seems to be actor) in my messages.
ex :
import "Proto.Actor/Protos.proto";

SomeMessage { 
  PID requester_pid = 1;
}

I tried importing the nuget package Proto.Actor, and then tried to import the protofile "Protos.proto" in my own protofile using :
Import "Proto.Actor/Protos.proto"
or
Import "Protos.proto"
I guess I may be missing something here.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !
